# Joomla 4 alpha display modal with insert image button

Tags: administrator, bootstrap, modal, media-manager, joomla-4

I am developing a custom module in Joomla4 alpha, using a bootstrap rendered modal window so that the user of the component will assign images from media in the Joomla back end to the extension gallery.

In Joomla3.x, there are insert and close buttons when the modal window comes up.

In Joomla4, there is not or I am missing something?

```
$html .= JHtmlBootstrap::renderModal(
             'myModal',
             array(
                 'url' => Uri::root() . 'administrator/index.php?option=com_media&amp;tmpl=component&amp;e_name=myslideimgname&amp;asset=com_modules&amp;author=&amp;path=' . '&amp;' . JSession::getFormToken() . '=1"',
                 'width' => '620px',
                 'height' => '390px'
             )
         );
```

In Joomla3.x, there is `view=images` in which the two buttons were added in its layout, in Joomla4 alpha there is not such a view, only file and media views.

The way around this problem is to make the user create a folder in the images folder of Joomla, add images there, then read those images in the layout of the extension from the folder.

However, if there is a solution to add the insert button, I would rather employ it.

Comment: Your very long `url` value reminded me to ask [this question](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/26632/12352).  Please consider adopting `http_build_query()` to improve stability and readability.  This will help to prevent typos (like `"` at the end).

Comment: This is the example to mention the situation, In my extension I employed HTMLHelper::_('bootstrap.renderModal', '', $params), joomla CMS will take care of it.

Comment: My claim is based on more than 350 custom extensions I analyzed after download from Joomla Extension Directory and in none of them  any developer employed http_build_query(). This is a pure PHP function, the phylosophy of a CMS is to handle  many functionalities including security. In some extensions in folder model parts of the component extension I observed that, yet in extensions which create modals , I have never seen any developer employ http_build_query() while assigning a url to $params['url'], it is the way as it is. You can conclude the same result if you like.

Comment: The fact that many Joomla extention developers do not call upon `http_build_query()` is 1. not a surprise to me, 2. likely due to so many Joomla devs being predisposed to "copy-pasting what has worked before", 3. probably because they are unaware that the function exists.  Just because lots of people in a demographic aren't doing something, doesn't mean that something shouldn't be done. I am here to inform and educate ...and receive help when I need it.

Comment: If you hid my response, I shall conculde you read it, it was too long for comment part. That is enough for me.

Comment: If you can hid a response, you may add to the length of textbox for comments so that I will be able to respond your question in comment part. Also in a forum no body educates no body, it is a place to exchange ideas to improve intelligence and experience for all, computer is a relative field, no human on planet could claim as a teacher!

Comment: I have read the deleted answer, but I fail to see how it argues against my advice.  Building an array of query string parameters then attaching that data to the url via `http_build_query()` will result in highly readable code that doesn't require horizontal scrolling or concatenation AND it automatically encodes the data to suit the url.  My advice has no drawbacks.  This is why I recommend it.  If you don't want to use it in your code, that is your prerogative.

Comment: You are going off the rails a bit here.  First, if you don't have enough room to make a single comment due to length, then make two consecutive comments. (I have no authority to change the maximum character limit of comments.)  Second, I fundamentally disagree about the purpose of this community -- we are all here to generously educate each other.  It is not about saying "I know more than you", it is about saying "look what I can show you and why it is a good idea".

Comment: I assure you all developers in joomla aware of http_build_query(), it is as famous as PHP word itself, any way, no argue, next time I shall make more comments, you also expect an answer in related thread, it is called classification of a thread according to related subject AND I have never used http_build_query() in my modal and I did not experience that horizontal scroll problem or concatenation.

Comment: Here is a link from a tutorial of joomla AND if you see your php function there, let me Know:https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Adding_a_Modal

Comment: I don't know why you insist on arguing.  I am going to disengage from this go-no-where discussion. I am trying to offer you good advice.  If you don't understand the benefits, I cannot explain the advantages any better.  The fact that this function call is not in the docs or core code makes no difference to sharing a useful technique with you. Maybe the core devs will one day adopt this technique.  I'm  done.  Reply if you need the last word.

Comment: You yourself asked for a proof to support my claim, this is an upbeat joomla 3.x tutorial about creation of a modal window. I can send you more than a dozen tutorials about modal in joomla CMS and in none you find http_build_query() while assigning url to params array to render a modal. It is good to give advice but the advice must be logical AND with no AND.